# How can I access the text within an WPF text box as a string from c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

I am building a form which has the usual form of text box next to a "browse..." button. If a file is browsed for, it is then pasted into the text box.

I want to be able to use a separate function to read in the file, but I can't find any way of getting the text outside the scope of the function that pastes it upon closing the browse dialog.

So the XAML text is this:

```
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">Source File:</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"   Name="FileNameTextBox" Margin="2"></TextBox>
        <Button Grid.Column="3" Margin="2" Name="button1" Click="button1_Click" Grid.Row="4">Browse...</Button>
```

And the C# code behind it is this:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create OpenFileDialog
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

    // Set filter for file extension and default file extension
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
    dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt";

    // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

    // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox
    if (result == true)
    {
        // Open document
        string filename = dlg.FileName;
        FileNameTextBox.Text = filename;
    }
}
```

I'm new to all this, so please explain it in a way I can understand, if possible... But after doing this, why can I not refer to the text in another function with "FileNameTextBox.Text" again? Doesn't that exist in XAML, not in the C# code? The new function can't "see" it.

I feel like it's somehow due to having "(object sender..." in the browse function, but I can't see a way to do this same kind of thing again without making a "Read what you just browsed for" button after it, which would make no sense.

Would {binding} the text box into this other code somehow work out? I haven't found a description of that which has allowed me to understand it well enough to use that at all, so far.

Even if that did work, I still don't get which places I can, and cant, declare a "DataContext", as it isn't suggested half the time.

EDIT: So, I came back to it later on in the day and, through what I can only image is a classic case of adding or deleting a curvy bracket, C# was suddenly able to detect the object FileNameTextBox where I was typing. Wack. Anyway, thanks, everyone.

Comment: Your Text Box is named: FileNameTextBox. So in most of the methods in your code behind (where you handled the browse button click) - you should be able to access textbox via its name.

Comment: Have you considered first reading an introductory WPF book? I'd recommend Adam Nathan's *WPF Unleashed*.

Comment: Just Use: "NameOFTextBox.Text"  to get the link to that file as you have already pasted the link to the textBox.

Comment: Thanks, Clemens. I'm trying to learn all I can, as fast as I can. Will take a look!

Comment: Has some college started a WPF course recently - there seems to have been a spate of very similar questions over the past few days.